# display none in media query not working for menu icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am creating a landing page using HTML/CSS and javascript. For media query, `max-width: 768px` is working fine but when I used media query for `min-width: 768px`, the `display: block`, is not removing the menu bar for screen size greater than 768px.

```css
@media screen and(min-width: 768px){

  body{
    margin: 0;
  }

  .nav{
    height: calc( var(--header-height) + 3rem);
  }

  .nav-toggle .nav-close{
    display: none;
  }

}
```

here `.nav-toggle` is the hamburger icon class and `.nav-close` is the class for the cross(X) button. I used `display` property but it is still showing the toggle.

Comment: Please post all of the CSS pertaining to .nav-toggle and .nav-close along with the your HTML.  It will make it much easier for us to help you.  Thank you.

Comment: Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

it's' all about targeting the right classes

try to inspect via your browser devtools in your targeted size you will probably notice that your css is overridden in this case you can try more specific classes to increase the css specificity or force your css via !important tag

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).